Narrowing the prime search using CRT composite sequences.
Bertrand's Theorem
Bertrand's Theorem guarantees a prime in the interval $[n, 2n]$.
Chinese Remainder Theorem
The Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT) general solution is given by
$$
x = Lk + r
$$
where

$L$ is the least common multiple of the moduli
$r$ is the particular remainder
$k \in$ $\mathbb{Z}$


Goal
The idea is to partially fill Bertrand's interval with composite sequences using the CRT to narrow the search for primes.
We solve for $x$ in Bertrand's interval $[n, 2n]$
$$n \leq x = Lk + r \leq 2n$$
Rearranging gives
$$\left\lceil \frac{n - r}{L} \right\rceil \leq k \leq \left\lfloor \frac{2n - r}{L} \right\rfloor$$
Example
Let the moduli be $2$, $3$, and $5$ (pairwise coprime) so these are composite numbers
$$
x+1, \quad x+2, \quad x+3
$$
Using WolframAlpha to solve the system of congruences gives $L = 30$ and $r=7$
Reduce[{Mod[x+1,2]==Mod[0,2],Mod[x+2,3]==Mod[0,3],Mod[x+3,5]==Mod[0,5]},{x},Integers]
Let $n = 100$ and note $4 \leq k \leq 6$ since
$$\left\lceil \frac{100 - 7}{30} \right\rceil \leq k \leq \left\lfloor \frac{200 - 7}{30} \right\rfloor$$
For each $k$, we calculate

$k = 4$: $x = 30 \times 4 + 7 = 127$
$k = 5$: $x = 30 \times 5 + 7 = 157$
$k = 6$: $x = 30 \times 6 + 7 = 187$

Visually, the interval $[100, 200]$ is approx $10\%$ covered
$\large [100, \dots, \overbrace{128, 129, 130}^{k=4}, \dots, \overbrace{158, 159, 160}^{k=5}, \dots, \overbrace{188, 189, 190}^{k=6}, \dots, 200]$

Question
How can it be optimized to cover the maximum portion of a given interval (e.g., Bertrand’s interval) with composites, leaving minimal gaps where primes could exist?
Maybe combine multiple composite sequence generators targeting $[n,2n]$?
$
\text{Composites} = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
(m+1)! + k, & \quad k = 2 \text{ to } m+1, \quad x \in [n, 2n] 
\quad(Factorial) \\
p\# + k, & \quad k = 2 \text{ to } p, \quad x \in [n, 2n] \quad(Primorial) \\
x = L \cdot q + r, & \quad x \in [n, 2n] \quad(CRT)
\end{array}
\right.
$
